# Understanding Java Opts Locale Settings

Tags: java, encoding, jvm, java-opts

Basically, what is the difference between LANG and user.language?

I've got the following java opts set:

```
-DLANG=de_DE.UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=EN
```

However, if my `*.properties` file contains an special character like `äöü` it's not properly formatted in my webapp.

However, if I set the proper unicode for the special character like `M\u00E4ngeldaten -> \u00E4 = ä` (ref: [UTF-8 table](http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/)) it's properly formatted.

*I've also made sure my IDE uses UTF-8 as default encoding.*

Why is that behaviour eventhough i've set file encoding UTF-8 for my JBoss instance AND Eclipse IDE?

Comment: With "I've made sure my IDE uses UTF-8 as default encoding", you mean "I'm sure the file really is UTF-8 encoded"? Try opening with eg. Notepad++ and check the Encoding.

Comment: @daniu it **is** UTF-8, even with NPP